# Programming convention in LaTeX: top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top?

Tags: best-practices, programming

When writing a package, should one use the top-to-bottom approach or bottom-to-top?

For example, the following two methods (in expl3 syntax)

```
% Top-to-bottom
\NewDocumentCommand \foo {m} { \mytest_foo:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \mytest_foo:n #1 { \__mytest_foo_aux:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__mytest_foo_aux:n #1 { some~ code~ of~ #1 }
```

and

```
% Bottom-to-top
\cs_new:Npn \__mytest_foo_aux:n #1 { some~ code~ of~ #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \mytest_foo:n #1 { \__mytest_foo_aux:n {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \foo {m} { \mytest_foo:n {#1} }
```

Which one is better?

Comment: IMHO the one you like and understand better.

Comment: I agree with Skillmon. Just don't mix it.

Answer (score 6):

Well really it makes no difference

```
\cs_new:Npn \mytest_foo:n #1 { \__mytest_foo_aux:n {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \foo {m} { \mytest_foo:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__mytest_foo_aux:n #1 { some~ code~ of~ #1 }
```

works as well.

For larger projects one may find the "implementation" (using `expl3` conventions) in a different file than the "user interface specification" (using `xparse`) so the order of loading may vary by document even if the code is unchanged.

`xparse` is designed around the idea of specifying one or more LaTeX2e-style interfaces over some underlying implemented functionality, so whether you put the specification before the implementation depends mostly on how you want to document things, although the documentation doesn't necessarily need to follow the code. You may have written the lower level `expl3` code before adding the `xparse` interface, or you may spec out a user interface using `xparse` and then later implement something to support it.